# nut usbhid-ups loosing connection after some time

Tags: udev, usb-device, ups, nut

I have a CyperPower OR500LCDRM1U connected via USB to nut on Debian (proxmox). After some time (hours?), the connection to UPS is lost. Extremely frustrating because UPS is a critical component. It *might* be that USB reinitializes, temporarily device becomes unavailable for a few seconds or similar. I don't know. Nothing in particular in the logs but I can't really monitor it either because it only happens after several hours and then I see realize it the next day.

Regardless, my expectation is that in this case it should just re-open the device!

My logs become filled with

```
Jul 30 00:19:36 pve1 upsmon[2066730]: UPS [ups@localhost]: connect failed: Connection failure: Connection timed out
Jul 30 00:19:36 pve1 upsmon[2066730]: UPS ups@localhost is unavailable
Jul 30 00:21:51 pve1 upsmon[2066730]: UPS [ups@localhost]: connect failed: Connection failure: Connection timed out
Jul 30 00:24:06 pve1 upsmon[2066730]: UPS [ups@localhost]: connect failed: Connection failure: Connection timed out
Jul 30 00:26:21 pve1 upsmon[2066730]: UPS [ups@localhost]: connect failed: Connection failure: Connection timed out
Jul 30 00:26:21 pve1 upsmon[2066730]: UPS ups@localhost is unavailable
```

When I `strace -p` the `usbhid-ups -a ups` process, I get:

```
select(7, [5 6], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=898414}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB, 0x7ffe4f699750) = 0
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
select(5, NULL, [4], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 1 (out [4], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=251})
ioctl(4, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffe4f699718) = 0
```

If I restart the nut driver (`systemctl restart nut-driver.service`) it always works again (for a few hours).

I have created `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-nut-ups.rules` with content:

```
# Rule for the UPS - use lsusb for idVendor and idProduct
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0764", ATTR{idProduct}=="0601", MODE="0660", GROUP="nut"
```

In my `/etc/nut/ups.conf` I have:

```
maxretry = 3

[ups]
driver = usbhid-ups
port = auto
desc = "CyberPower PR1500LCDRT2U"
vendorid = 0764
productid = 0601
```

My UPS becomes available as the following device file:

```
# ls -la /dev/bus/usb/001/004 
crw-rw-r-- 1 root nut 189, 3 Aug  4 02:30 /dev/bus/usb/001/004
```

I am not providing the remaining nut config files because the issue is clearly related to the usbhid-ups driver and connection via `upsc ups` fails.

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
11.6
# uname -a
Linux pve1 5.15.85-1-pve #1 SMP PVE 5.15.85-1 (2023-02-01T00:00Z) x86_64 GNU/Linux
#
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Hey divB, did you ever end up figuring this out?

Comment: @Alexander see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried [this might be a `DenverCoder9` situation](https://xkcd.com/979/) haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by increasing the `pollInterval` from the default (2 seconds) to 15 seconds.

`/etc/nut/ups.conf`:

```ini
maxretry = 3

[ups]
    driver = usbhid-ups
    port = auto
    desc = "CyberPower PR1500LCDRT2U"
    vendorid = 0764
    productid = 0601
    pollinterval = 15 # seconds
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much for sharing! The default value of this was `2` (seconds), and it's not clear to me while pooling less often keeps my UPS (CyberPower BRG850AVRLCD) from disconnecting, but it works! I also got it down to 5 secondse, and it still worked fine.

Comment: Even 3 seconds worked :)